What is the simplest way to think of and give expression to Dhamma for practical purposes for meditation?
What is the simplest way to think of and give expression to Dhamma for practical purposes for meditators? What exactly is Dukkha?


No origin no effects

There's no easy way to explain Nibbāna, except the Buddha who practiced, experienced, 4 Asaṅheyya and over 100k Kappa to be a teacher.
His followers as well. Who have practice long enough and right enough are the survivors, but mostly not.
Why?
Because most people try to cut the Buddha's experience off, to get the easier path which the Buddha experienced  then said "No, do not".
And that's why most people avoid practice follow the first two very long Suttas ^.^

Dukkha is dissatisfaction. Tanhā is the persistent urge or longing to resolve dissatisfaction. One aspect of the practice of meditation is that the act itself — sitting quietly and doing nothing — is a petri dish for dissatisfactions and urges. As we sit there, every little dissatisfaction we have will rise to our attention, and the thinking mind will grasp at it and start worrying or planning or fantasizing about how it can be resolved. But because we're sitting quietly and not doing anything, this mental activity becomes obvious and awkward: no longer concealed by the hustle and bustle of daily life.
When we watch this mental activity and do nothing with it, we train the mind that this kind of mental activity isn't important. Dissatisfactions and urges arise less frequently and more functionally, and the mental energy we put into that arising is released.
Of course, there's more depth to meditation than this, but this is a useful way to grasp the pragmatics.

In the teachings of the Buddha, the word 'dukkha' has three different meanings:

In teachings related to the Four Noble Truths & Dependent Origination, the word 'dukkha' means 'suffering', i.e., 'mental torment'. The Buddha & his Arahant disciples did not experience any of this meaning of dukkha. This 'dukkha' is 'attachment' or 'egoist obsession'. Some simple suttas explaining this are SN 22.1 and SN 36.6.

In teachings related to the Three Characteristics, the word 'dukkha' means 'unpleasurableness', i.e., 'unsatisfactoriness'. It does not refer to a state of mind but refers to the incapacity of impermanent things to bring lasting happiness. The Buddha & his Arahant disciples always experienced this meaning of dukkha when observing the impermanent & condition things of the world. Experiencing this meaning of 'dukkha' causes disenchantment, dispassion, the ending of craving & the ending of suffering.

In teachings related to the feelings arising from sense contact, the word 'dukkha' means 'unpleasant' or 'painful'. These 'unpleasant' feelings or sensations are not suffering. The Buddha & his Arahant disciples experienced unpleasant sense impressions but were without greed, hatred, delusion & attachment towards these feelings from sense impacts.


Another way to distinguish the three meanings of 'dukkha' is as follows:

The 1st type of dukkha is caused by craving.

The 2nd type of dukkha is caused by impermanence.

The 3rd type of dukkha is caused by sense contact.


The simplest way to think of and give expression to Dhamma for practical purposes for meditators is the Path of Dhamma is the abandonment of craving. Meditation is watching over the mind to ensure the mind remains without craving.

I recently heard a talk from Ajahn Sumedho, who said people will ask him to summarize the Dhamma in one sentence, and he says he can do it in one, "awake". (see "Ajahn Sumedho - Pointing at You" on youtube)
Dukkha is conditioned, arising, changing, ceasing things, and our grasping and aversion toward them, which is also conditioned.

... when there is arising, only stress is arising; and that when there is passing away, only stress is passing away. ... It is to this extent, Kaccayana, that there is right view. -SN 12.15


An answer:
The quick answer that "everything is Dukkha" doesn't help with coming to its cessation.
For all practical purposes, an active meditator needs to know the essence of Dhamma so as to know what s/he is supposed to be doing in the attempt to heal or ease Dukkha, dissatisfaction, frustration within the present moment.
A training of the mind is called for that lies beyond simple exercises of mindfulness of changes in bodily functions and activities.
A clarity of view.
At the core of this is the concept of Ignorance.
Within the context of Dhamma, ignorance is specifically that the practitioner doesn't know that s/he doesn't know about a current issue. In short, the practitioner has activities running in the present moment quite unknowingly and s/he doesn't know this.
For example, identification with a self, or being, behind the perceptions and feelings that are running in the present moment, the "here and now", is quite unknown to the beginning practitioner.
In its simplest terms, knowing the difference between Subject and Object within the dynamics of mental activity. More specifically, how a Subject may be Objectified with simple, accurate labelling once this dilemma is sufficiently clear to the practitioner.

In its simplest form: What is Ignorance?
Not knowing that you are ignorant.
Not knowing the differences and functions of Subjectivity and Objectivity in the Conscious domain.
Beavering away at questions of the nature of: Who am I? What am I? Who was I? Who will I be? Having been, what will I be?
Getting caught up in such tangles and then to include such tangles as Objects within the Conscious or Subjective domain.

Please see this answer on Buddhism Meta. We don't prefer seeded questions that you answer yourself. But it won't be deleted.
